# Xamarin.forms How to play an android notification sound

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am using **Xaminn.Forms** PLC project, right now I am trying to set sound for notification on android project, I add the notification to my project using:

```
assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (NotificationService))]
```

on the following my code used to display the notification:

```
   var notification = new Notification.Builder (Application.Context)
    .SetContentTitle (message.Short_Message.ToString ())
    .SetContentText (message.Long_Message.ToString())
    .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)  
    .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message.Long_Message))   
    .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max) 
    .SetContentIntent(OpenAppOnCLickOnNotificaton)   
    .SetLights(255,1000,1000)
    .Build ();

    var manager = Application.Context.GetSystemService (Application.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        manager.Notify (message.ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use Default Notification Sound as the following:

```
  .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
```

Comment: working fine, but how I can set my custom notification sound ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried with above line for getting sounds but not luck. Please suggest what I am missing.